# Prevent urls in string in php

Tags: php, regex, url

Hello i tried to prevent insert url in string like this:

```
function containsURL($string) {
    //check if string contains url
    $remove = array(" ", "!", ",", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")");
    $string = str_replace($remove, "", $string);
    $regex = "((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME 
    $regex .= "([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?"; // User and Pass 
    $regex .= "([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})"; // Host or IP 
    $regex .= "(\:[0-9]{2,5})?"; // Port 
    $regex .= "(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?"; // Path 
    $regex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?"; // GET Query 
    $regex .= "(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?"; // Anchor 

   if(preg_match("/^{$regex}$/", $string)) //contains
        return true;
   return false;
}
```

but its not prevent everything
urls like this:

```
bit.ly/18SuUzJ (with http)
```

its not prevent
or like this

```
bit.ly/18SuUzJ (without http)
```

or other url shorter generators...

but i need to do?
tnx

Comment: What's the purpose of the `str_replace`? What decides which character *stays*, and which *goes*?

Comment: @ClasG the purpose is when the user enter url like this: w w w . c o m . c o m (with spaces) its remove the spaces and check if he enter url (same for all the chars in the array)

Comment: So URL's like `http://example.com/search?q=why&lang=id#1` aren't allowed?

Comment: Your final regex looks like [`^((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=$_.-]+)?@)?([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+$_.-]*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/kJ3hW3/1) and it does not match those short URLs. Do you want to match them? [**Add the `/i` modifier**](https://regex101.com/r/kJ3hW3/2).

Comment: If you're replacing spaces and then checking for "urls" you'd also block "*they entered the door. He/she was standing in the doorway.*" as it'd change to "theyenteredthedoor.he/shewasstandinginthedoorway" and according to you that's an URL (if bit.ly/12341234 is).

Comment: @ClasG Yes, they don't. actually i dont want urls never mind from where or what.

Answer (score 1):

Your final regex looks like [`^((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=$_.-]+)?@)?([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+$_.-]*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/kJ3hW3/1) and it does not match shortened URLs because you only defined lowercase ASCII letters in different regex parts.

If you want to match them the shortened URLs, [*add the case insensitive `/i` modifier*](https://regex101.com/r/kJ3hW3/2):

```
if(preg_match("/^{$regex}$/i", $string))
                           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun

```
(?:\b[a-z\d.-]+://[^<>\s]+|\b(?:(?:(?:[^\s!@#$%^&*()_=+[\]{}\|;:'",.<>/?]+)\.)+(?:ac|ad|aero|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|arpa|ar|asia|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|biz|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|cat|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|coop|com|co|cr|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|info|int|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jobs|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mobi|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|museum|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|name|na|nc|net|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pro|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tel|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|travel|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|xn--0zwm56d|xn--11b5bs3a9aj6g|xn--80akhbyknj4f|xn--9t4b11yi5a|xn--deba0ad|xn--g6w251d|xn--hgbk6aj7f53bba|xn--hlcj6aya9esc7a|xn--jxalpdlp|xn--kgbechtv|xn--zckzah|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)|(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[0-9]|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))(?:[;/][^#?<>\s]*)?(?:\?[^#<>\s]*)?(?:#[^<>\s]*)?(?!\w))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zR1tZ8/1)